# Concatenate several TIFF movies with ImageMagick in Windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd, imagemagick, concatenation, image-editing

I would like to concatenate several TIFF movies (each of the movies contains 1023 frames) with ImageMagick using the command prompt. Here is the scheme:

```
Directory of C:\Data\DEFAULT_USER\image\1

06/13/2017  11:49 AM    <DIR>          .
06/13/2017  11:49 AM    <DIR>          ..
06/12/2017  03:29 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms.tif
06/12/2017  03:32 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_1.tif
06/12/2017  03:55 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_10.tif
06/12/2017  03:57 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_11.tif
06/12/2017  04:00 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_12.tif
06/12/2017  04:02 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_13.tif
06/12/2017  04:05 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_14.tif
06/12/2017  04:07 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_15.tif
06/12/2017  04:10 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_16.tif
06/12/2017  04:13 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_17.tif
06/12/2017  04:15 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_18.tif
06/12/2017  04:18 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_19.tif
06/12/2017  03:34 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_2.tif
06/12/2017  04:20 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_20.tif
06/12/2017  04:23 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_21.tif
06/12/2017  04:25 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_22.tif
06/12/2017  04:28 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_23.tif
06/12/2017  04:30 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_24.tif
06/12/2017  04:33 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_25.tif
06/12/2017  04:36 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_26.tif
06/12/2017  04:38 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_27.tif
06/12/2017  04:41 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_28.tif
06/12/2017  04:42 PM       698,868,440 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_29.tif
06/12/2017  03:37 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_3.tif
06/12/2017  03:39 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_4.tif
06/12/2017  03:42 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_5.tif
06/12/2017  03:44 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_6.tif
06/12/2017  03:47 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_7.tif
06/12/2017  03:50 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_8.tif
06/12/2017  03:52 PM     2,146,974,200 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_9.tif

              40 File(s) 64,922,694,520 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  113,764,110,336 bytes free
```

I would like to concatenate all of those TIFF files. I tried:

```
C:\Data\DEFAULT_USER\image\1>convert +append 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms.tif 1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_1.tif outpu.tif
```

but I got some error messages like this:

```
convert: ASCII value for tag "ImageDescription" contains null byte in value; value incorrectly truncated during reading due to implementation limitations. `TIFFFetchNormalTag' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/925.
convert: improper image header `1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms.tif' @ error/tiff.c/ReadTIFFImage/1236.
convert: ASCII value for tag "ImageDescription" contains null byte in value; value incorrectly truncated during reading due to implementation limitations. `TIFFFetchNormalTag' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/925.
convert: improper image header `1_2017-06-12_15h27m02s121ms_1.tif' @ error/tiff.c/ReadTIFFImage/1236.
convert: no images defined `outpu.tif' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3254.
```

How do I work these things out?

Comment: It would seem that your TIF files are not compatible. What is your version of ImageMagick and libtif. What is your platform/OS (assumed Windows)? Can you post one tiff file, so it can be examined in current versions of ImageMagick.  Proper ImageMagick syntax is to read all the input images, then +append, then the output. Perhaps there is a width limitation for your appended tif files? How big are they (dimensions)

Comment: CONTINUED: Sorry, I see from your title, you are using Windows 10. But what version of ImageMagick. What do you mean by concatenate? Do you really mean put them side-by-side using +append? Or do you want a multi-page TIFF?  It would seem that your ImageDescription field contains bad characters, so your files may not be properly formatted according to the TIFF specs. It could be a bug in ImageMagick or liftoff. So posting an example image would help resolve this. Your files appear to be 2 GB each. Those are large files to be appending, especially if you want to append 1023 of them!

Comment: Hi. yes I wanna make a multi page tif. i am using image magick for windows of this version ImageMagick-7.0.6-0-Q16-x64-dll.exe

Comment: the dimensions are 1024 x 1024

Answer (score 1):

In imagemagick, to create a multipage tif, you do

```
convert image1.tif image2.tif ... imageN.tif newimage.tif
```

Do not include +append, which will try to put them side-by-side in one wide image. Use your own image names. Or put them all in one directory with nothing else in there and rename them in alphabetic order. Then you can do

```
convert *.tif newimage.tif
```

You can add whatever tif compression you want or -compress none, if you do not want any compression. You can set the depth however you want also and also the type. See the TIFF section at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php for other tiff options. See also http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#depth and 
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#type and 
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#compress